# How to prevent BeautifulSoup from stripping lines

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to translate an online html page into text.

I have a problem with this structure:

```
<div align="justify"><b>Available in  
<a href="http://www.example.com.be/book.php?number=1">
French</a> and 
<a href="http://www.example.com.be/book.php?number=5">
English</a>.
</div>
```

Here is its representation as a python string:

```
'<div align="justify"><b>Available in  \r\n<a href="http://www.example.com.be/book.php?number=1">\r\nFrench</a>; \r\n<a href="http://www.example.com.be/book.php?number=5">\r\nEnglish</a>.\r\n</div>'
```

When using:

```
html_content = get_html_div_from_above()
para = BeautifulSoup(html_content)
txt = para.text
```

BeautifulSoup translate it (in the 'txt' variable) as:

```
u'Available inFrenchandEnglish.'
```

It probably strips each line in the original html string.

Do you have a clean solution about this problem ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally got a good solution:

```
def clean_line(line):
    return re.sub(r'[ ]{2,}', ' ', re.sub(r'[\r\n]', '', line))

html_content = get_html_div_from_above()
para = BeautifulSoup(html_content)
''.join([clean_line(line) for line in para.findAll(text=True)])
```

Which outputs:

```
u'Available in French and English.  '
```

Answer (score 1):

I got a solution:

```
html_content = get_html_div_from_above()
para = BeautifulSoup(html_content)
txt = para.getText(separator=' ')
```

But it's not optimal because it puts spaces between each tag:

```
u'Available in French and English .  '
```

Notice the space before the dot.